# NAnt nCover использование white box и black box тестов

Tags: сборка, code-coverage, nant, .net

Добрый день.
Есть два проекта .Net:
 - `Project.dll` - сборка, покрытие которой нужно оценить
 - `ProjectBlackBoxTests.dll` - сборка, производящая black box тесты для первого проекта.

Сама сборки `Project.dll` тоже содержит white box тесты.
Нужно оценить покрытие кода сборки `Project.dll` запустив тесты white box и black box.

---

- Пробовал запускать оба теста одной командой `ncover` (отчет пишется в один файл)

  `<target name="ncover">
  ...
    <ncover program="${ncover.console}"
      excludeAttributes="ExcludeAttribute"
      testRunnerExe="${nunit.console}"
      testRunnerArgs="Project.dll ProjectBlackBoxTests.dll"
      coverageFile="coverage.xml"
    </ncover>
  </target>`
- Пробовал запускать двумя разными запусками `ncover` (отчеты пишутся в разные файлы), при ncoverreporting указываю оба файла отчета

  `<ncoverreporting program="${ncover.reporting}"  projectName="Project">
      <coverageDataPaths>
        <include name="сoverage.xml" />
        <include name="сoverageBlackBox.xml" />
      </coverageDataPaths>
      <reports>
      ...
      </reports>
    </ncoverreporting>`

В результате, результаты второго запуска *заменяют* результаты первого запуска, а *не объединяются*.

Кто нибудь подобное делал, как это решается?